# MagicalRecord + AFNetworking + NSFetchedResultsController, how to make it work?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, afnetworking, magicalrecord

In my application I try to use MagicalRecord + AFNetworking  + NSFetchedResultsController together, to synchronize data and dynamically display it on map or in tableView.

Let's see some code for download method:

```
+ (void) getDataWithCompletionBlock: (void (^)(void)) block {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_GET_DATA]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            for (NSDictionary *dict in JSON) {
                [MyModel createOrUpdateMyModelFromDict:[dict mutableCopy]];
            }

            [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveInBackgroundCompletion:^{
                [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveNestedContexts];

                block();
            }];
        });

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        DDLogError(@"getDataWithCompletionBlock FAILURE: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

I download data using `AFJSONRequestOperation`, then create models using GCD and background thread, save context for current thread and perform `successBlock` (MagicalRecord runs `successBlock` on `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, so it is called in GUI thread.

Is this synchronization model ok ? Because sometimes (more often on real device than simulator) I get some errors from `NSFetchedResultsController` like "no object at index: in section at index:" or "CoreData could not fulfill a fault...".

They all suggest, there is something wrong with Core Data and multithreading environment. Did anyone try to connect all these three tools to work together ? If so, what am I missing ? Do you have any good-working code samples for that architecture ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using:

`[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block];`

It handles threading for you so you don't have to worry about anything getting saved on the parent context from a background context.

I highly encourage you to read this blog post (written by the creator of MagicalRecord Saul Mora): [IMPORTING DATA MADE EASY](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/). It super good background information about the workings of MagicalRecord and an example of how to use it.

If you setup your Data Model correctly you can actually have MagicalRecord do all the mapping for you and all you have to do is call `importFromObject:` inside the `saveWithBlock:` block and you don't have to worry about dealing with the mapping. The article I linked to above goes into detail about how to do it properly, but it will take some practice.